# Stream Relaying for large uploads

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, stream, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET web app (MVC4, Web API) that needs to receive large uploads (videos >500MB) via Multipart POST requests.  I am trying to improve user experience by relaying the incoming stream of the video part directly to the server that will process and store the video (Kaltura).  This is to be an improvement over the current process which stores the video in a file on the filesystem which is later retrieved by the video server.

I've done this by creating a subclass of MultipartStreamProvider called RelayingStreamProvider. I pass it the request stream of a WebRequest I've created to the Kaltura server and it uses this for writing.  When I construct the RelayingStreamProvider, I wrap the request stream in a BufferedStream to handle any latency or interruptions on either the reading or writing side of this process.

I've turned off Request buffering in my Web API controller as well.

My questions:

1. Am I overlooking anything that will likely bite me later with this approach?  I'm trying to constrain for efficiency by keeping the filesystem out of the process.  On the upside, multiple simultaneous 500 MB uploads are consuming essentially no memory in my test implementation.  Downsides?
2. I'm using a 32KB buffer for my BufferedStream.  Is this a reasonable figure?  What are the reasons to make this larger/smaller?

Finally, I am indeed aware that there is a widget and mobile APIs I can use to take myself out of the middleman role for Kaltura.  And we are going to be implementing these.  Since the widget requires Flash, we are using this approach as a fallback for users who don't have Flash.